# ReferenceError: $modal is not defined when trying to add an angularjs modal window

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I get that error when I'm trying to implement this http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#modal in my application. Why is it so? Maybe I haven't added something correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to declare dependency.
In their [documentation on github](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/) you can find this:

> Inject the $strap.directives into your app module

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['$strap.directives']);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the issue, maybe there's something else that I need to do?

Comment: Show your code (in plunker or jsFiddle), because it's difficult to predict.

Comment: you forgot to include angular.js, declare controller and set controller for dom node (html or body).