# Angular Bootstrap Modal: Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Angular Bootstrap Modal directive (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) as follows, in my controller to open the modal:

```
function customerSearch() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/customer/customers.modal.html',
        controller: 'customers.modal'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedCustomer) {
        console.log(selectedCustomer);
    });
}
```

In the modal controller:

```
var controllerId = 'customers.modal';

angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$modalInstance', customersModal]);

function customersModal($modalInstance) {
    // Modal controller stuff
}
```

But when I do, I get the following error:

```
Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance
```

If I take out `$modalInstance`, it works but I obviously have no reference to the modal in the calling controller..

### Edit

I don't know if it is worth noting, but I am using the Controller As syntax:

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-controller="customers.modal as vm">
```

Application dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules 
    'ngAnimate',        // animations
    'ngRoute',          // routing
    'ngSanitize',       // sanitizes html bindings (ex: sidebar.js)

    // Custom modules 
    'common',           // common functions, logger, spinner
    'common.bootstrap', // bootstrap dialog wrapper functions

    // 3rd Party Modules
    'ui.bootstrap',      // ui-bootstrap (ex: carousel, pagination, dialog)
    'breeze.directives', // breeze validation directive (zValidate)
]);
```

I've created a plunker which is showing the problem here: http://plnkr.co/edit/u8MSSegOnUQgsA36SMhg?p=preview

Comment: Have created a custom directive or used the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ directives

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using the one found at that url: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Ok you have a very strange way to declare the controller in 3 steps. can mess up name resolving if angular is tyring to find the function.

Comment: can you show where you declare your module's dependencies?

Comment: I find it easier to manage and perform logging operations this way

Comment: @IlanFrumer I've edited my question to show dependencies

Comment: Looking at the plunkr on the main site the dependency is `function ($scope, $modal, $log)`, it's $modal not `$modalInstance`

Comment: @Chandermani That is for the controller which is calling the modal. The modal controller has $modalInstance as a dependency

Comment: Could you try to prepare a plunk with a minimal reproduce scenario?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The problem was that you were specifying a controller in 2 places - when opening a modal and inside a template - this is not needed. Remove ng-controller from a template and things will work as expected:
http://plnkr.co/edit/khySg1gJjqz1Qv4g4cS5?p=preview

Comment: What if I want to use the controller as syntax and remove controller form $modal.open()?

Comment: You can use the controller as syntax when opening a modal, as shown in the plunker. But $modalInstance is going to be injected only to controllers passed to the `open` method.

Comment: Is there no way to pass in $modalInstance when using controller as then? I seem to be having issues whereby my vm isnt updating: http://plnkr.co/edit/T4E38CmFqy9vsCtYurS7?p=preview

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I'm not sure what you are trying to do _exactly_ but maybe this plunker will help? http://plnkr.co/edit/OmWNr45yquoEMfq19HCg?p=preview - btw - there is no `ng-foreach` - you need to use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I remove the ng-controller and it works for me. But now I am confused. This plunker code from the angular directives bootstrap works and it have ng-controller in the html. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

try this syntax first

```
angular.module('app').controller('customers.modal',
    ['$modalInstance', function($modalInstance){
// Modal controller stuff
}]);
```

I think it get messed up if you use bracket notation and declare the controller outside.

$modalInstance is the modalInstance you create there

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/customer/customers.modal.html',
        controller: 'customers.modal'
    });
```

it's really the same object. It get injected back in the controller but it's not a service/factory. So it doesn't have a Provider.

This is a tricky part in the lib. Feel free to ask to the original authors of ui-bootstrap. They have been helpful in explaining that.

Comment: ok I didn't notice the template part.
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-controller="customers.modal as vm"> loads the controller maybe twice?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff you really should send a minimal plunker, otherwise we are all stabbing in the dark...

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I created a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/u8MSSegOnUQgsA36SMhg?p=preview