# Unit testing a modalInstance controller with Karma / Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-ui-bootstrap, karma-jasmine

**EDIT : Quick & Dirty solution at the end of this post**

I am using a modal window from AngularUI-Bootstrap in the same way that it is explained on the website, except that I splitted files.
Therefore I have :

**CallingController.js :**

```
$scope.delete = function () {
    if ($scope.selected.length > 0) {
        // [...]
        // preparing data
        // [...]
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/modalView.html',
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
            resolve: {
                itemArray: function () {
                    return $scope.selected;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (confirm) {
            if (confirm === true) {
                // [...]
                // treat
                // [...]
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**modalController.js :**

```
myAppControllers.controller('modalCtrl',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, itemArray) {

        $scope.accept = function () {
            $modalInstance.close(true);
        };

        $scope.reject = function () {
            $modalInstance.close(false);
        };

        $scope.itemArray = itemArray;

    });
```

and when I test this code with Karma (with the **ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js** file loaded in the karma configuration file), I get the following error : 
**Error: [$injector:unpr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15-build.2389+sha.c5f2f58/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance][1](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15-build.2389+sha.c5f2f58/%24injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance) at Error (native)**, meaning that jasmine doesn't manage to find the provider for $modalInstance.

I do not even test stuff on this controller, not yet, but here is my jasmine test file :

**testModalController.js :**

```
describe('Controller: modalCtrl', function () {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var Ctrl;
    var scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(
        function ($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            Ctrl = $controller('modalCtrl', { $scope: scope });
        })
    );

    describe('Initial state', function () {
        it('should instantiate the controller properly', function () {
            expect(Ctrl).not.toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should initialize its values properly', function () {

        });
    });

});
```

Have you got any clue about this problem ? It's not the first "external" module that I use (and test), and I did the same stuff than for the others, except that this time it doesn't work and I have no idea why.

**==========================================**

**EDIT: Quick & probably dirty solution :**

Okay, so based on the scope mocking method in the controller instantiation of Jasmine, I figured out how I could "solve" my problem, but it's probably quite dirty, so feel free to comment if you find a better way to do what I intend.

**testModalController.js :**

```
describe('Controller: modalCtrl', function () {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var Ctrl;
    var scope;
    var modalInstance;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(
        function ($controller, $rootScope, _$modal_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            modalInstance = _$modal_.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/modalView.html'
            });

            Ctrl = $controller('modalCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                $modalInstance: modalInstance,
                itemArray: function () { return ['a', 'b', 'c']; }
            });
        })
    );

    describe('Initial state', function () {
        it('should instantiate the controller properly', function () {
            expect(Ctrl).not.toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should initialize its values properly', function () {

        });
    });

});
```

This way, Jasmine doesn't search for providers anymore, because you already injected the items that are supposed to be needing those providers. It works, but I believe it could be done in a better way...

Comment: You need to load bootstrap module ('ui.bootstrap') or maybe ('ui.bootstrap.modal'). Try and tell me. Also a plunker always help.

Comment: Same thing. Added dependencies, but same error keeps popping in console window. Any solution? What is triggering it? I tried [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuBIcvbe08FqPc6wjyBq?p=preview) and it is working fine, but one step to the left in my app and it is sending this hellish error in console.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I am solving this by just creating mock `modal` and `modalInstance` objects and verifying that they have been called by my controller code. Since `modal` and `modalInstance` are part of a third party library, it's not our responsibility to test that they work properly - rather, it's our responsibility to test that our code which calls the library is working ok.

Using your example:

```
describe('Controller: modalCtrl', function () {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var Ctrl;
  var scope;
  var modalInstance;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(
    function ($controller, $rootScope) {     // Don't bother injecting a 'real' modal
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      modalInstance = {                    // Create a mock object using spies
        close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),
        dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss'),
        result: {
          then: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.result.then')
        }
      };
      Ctrl = $controller('modalCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $modalInstance: modalInstance,
        itemArray: function () { return ['a', 'b', 'c']; }
      });
    })
  );

  describe('Initial state', function () {
    it('should instantiate the controller properly', function () {
      expect(Ctrl).not.toBeUndefined();
    });

    it('should close the modal with result "true" when accepted', function () {
      scope.accept();
      expect(modalInstance.close).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    });

    it('should close the modal with result "false" when rejected', function () {
      scope.reject();
      expect(modalInstance.close).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
    });
  });
});
```

This way, we don't really need any dependency on the Angular-UI objects and our unit tests are nice and isolated.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I love it.  I've been struggling for a while now trying to test my modals in a good way, and I think this handles it nicely!

Comment: This is correct. It is important to add not to expect $modalInstance to be available to the injector in one's tests, as it would be to expect this of other services of the uiBootstrap module because $modalInstance is the instantiation of a new modal using the $modal service (which *is* available to the injector).

Answer (score 7):

Instead of:

```js
modalInstance = {                    // Create a mock object using spies
  close: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.close'),
  dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss'),
  result: {
    then: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.result.then')
  }
};
```

This can be written as:

```js
modalInstance = jasmine.createSpyObj('modalInstance', ['close', 'dismiss', 'result.then']);
```

Also there is no $modalInstance it is now $uibModalInstance so every "modalInstance" above should be replaced with "uibModalInstance"

Comment: +1 for the update about $uibModalInstance. Apparently this changed around the middle of October, 2015 when they moved from 0.14.3 to 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for fiznool's answer. it is correct and should be chosen..

I would like to note one thing though, it is not maintainable the way it is presented here.

Since this is angular, I suggest use it..

```
angular.module('...').service('$modalInstance', function(){
   ... define spies and such 
})
```

would make your code much more modular and generic. 
simply add a file under `spec` somewhere with the above content and make sure to include it in your `karma.conf`

if you want to make sure it loads only in specific tests, simply give it a unique module name and add it to `module` invocation in `beforeEach`