# Trying to dismiss a simple angular modal results in: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to have a simple modal appear when a user clicks something that is still under construction on my demo app.

Everything works up to the point where I want the user to click the 'Close' button on the modal. When they do they get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined

This is what I have in my main controller:

```
    $scope.underConstruction = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/underconstruction.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: 'sm',
        resolve: {
            '$modalInstance': function () { return function () { return modalInstance; } }
        }
    });
    console.log('modal opened');
    modalInstance.result.then(function (response) {
        $scope.selected = response;
        console.log(response);
    }, function () {
        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
```

Then in my ModalInstanceCtrl I have:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance) {
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
}]);
```

I'm  using angular-ui version 0.12.0, angularjs version v1.3.11

The close() method is hit, then the above error is thrown.

I have looked around at various results and questions and seen references to bugs and other issues, but the use cases are more complex than mine - my modal just shows some text and a close button. For example, I [found an answer that says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19205723/1559978):

> $modalInstance is made available for injection in the controller by AngularUI Bootstrap implementation. So, we don't need any effort ro "resolve" or make it available somehow.

Comment: Stewie answered correctly. You should get rid of this notation, and use *ngmin* or *ngannotate* while you are minifying your scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You deliberately "defined" your `$modalInstance` argument as `undefined` by not declaring it as a dependency in your Inline Annotation Array where you're declaring the `ModalInstanceCtrl` controller.

It should have been:

`['$scope', '$modal', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modal, $modalInstance){ ... }]`

The "*we don't need any effort...*" part does not mean you don't have to specify it as a dependency.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks. That's working more like I was expecting now.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to simplify things:

```
$scope.underConstruction = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/underconstruction.html'
    });
    console.log('modal opened');
};
```

Then in my modal template:

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$dismiss('cancel')">Close this message</button>
```

As per the documentation:

> In addition the scope associated with modal's content is augmented with 2 methods:
>
> $close(result)
>
> $dismiss(reason)
>
> Those methods make it easy to close a modal window without a need to create a > dedicated controller.

I did try this earlier but I guess either something else was interfering or I didn't clear my cache.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me

```
if(typeof(alert/popover)!="undefined"){
    await alert/popover.dismiss();
  }
```